# Finding the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below any given number

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge

I wrote the following simple function in JavaScript that finds the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below a value, given from a text-box.

I have used \$\dfrac{n}{2(a_1 + a_n)}\$ (sum of arithmetic sequence).

I was wondering if there is a way to shorten or otherwise improve this code.

```
function sum_of_all_mul_3_5(){
    var value=parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
    var result=(((Math.floor((value-1)/3))*(3+((Math.floor((value-1)/3))*3)))/2)+(((Math.floor((value-1)/5))*(5+((Math.floor((value-1)/5))*5)))/2)-(((Math.floor((value-1)/15))*(15+((Math.floor((value-1)/15))*15)))/2);
    document.getElementById("output").value=result ;
    }
```

Comment: Well mainly I tried to avoid loops in this,and yes I know my code is not in code standards but that's why I started to put code in here . To learn how to do it properly ,not be just shorten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take by "shorten", you mean "remove this duplication", in which case the answer is yes. Extract an `SumSequence` function. Give things some breathing space while you're at it.

```
function sum_of_all_mul_3_5(){
    var value=parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
    var result=sumSequence(value, 3) + sumSequence(value, 5) - sumSequence(value, 15);
    document.getElementById("output").value=result ;
    }

function sumSequence(value, x){
    return (Math.floor((value - 1) / x) * (x + ((Math.floor(value - 1) / x) * x))) / 2);
    }
```

For the record though, using the arithmetic sum of the sequence is a very elegant solution to this problem though. I know of no more efficient way to do it, but a comment explaining what's going on here would be beneficial to any future maintainer. You might even want to go the extra mile and drop a link to wikipedia in that comment.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest dividing calculation and Input/Output:

```
function sum_of_all_mul_3_5(limit){
    return sumSequence(value, 3) + sumSequence(value, 5) - sumSequence(value, 15);
    }
```

You can then use it in different ways such as:

```
alert(sum_of_all_mul_3_5(prompt("Max: ")))
```